# Not passing numberpicker decimal Integer to new Activity

Tags: java, android

I am passing Integer from numberPicker to new Activity. Problem is that picked value is not showing decimal value in new Activity. If I choose 90 and click ok buton to get to new Activity, it shows 9. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NumberPicker numberPicker= (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
                    int x=numberPicker.getValue();
                    Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main22Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("roundtime",x);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            }
    );

    String [] time= new String[10];
    for(int i=0;i<time.length;i++){
    time[i]=Integer.toString(i*10);
    }
    NumberPicker numberPicker= (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(time.length-1);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(time);

}
```

}

Here is my second Activity:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int msg=intent.getIntExtra("roundtime",0);
    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView.setText(Integer.toString(msg));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `int` if you want `decimal` value?
Use `double` instead.

How can you choose "90" if you setMax on your picker to be 9?

Comment: Hi Vucko. I saw it now that i wrote it wrong.Sorry for that!!! I do not want to pass decimal number, but I do have a problem passing int 90 to new Activity.

Comment: That is because you set your number picker max to `time.length()-1` which is 10-1 = 9. You need to set it to 100 or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I have setted Max in my picker to be 9,but that is because I used <for loop> to set numbers as I need. 10,20,30...90

Comment: Well you set the numbers to be 10, 20, 30.. 90 but the maximum value is still 9. just write `numberPicker.setMaxValue(90)` and it will work

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10 index=10
Poz brate u Srbiju

Comment: I think I get it. you have 10 different possible states of the number picker, 0,10,20 and so on. it returns the position of the picker, not the value - so when you select the value of 90, it actually returns the position of 9. You just need to map those positions back to the values. Poz matori, nadam se da ovo sad radi, aj pisi ako nece :D

Comment: Matore,znas sta mi javlja na 22 mjestu gresku :) MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) evo sa sam napisao kako si rekao        String [] time= {"0","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90"};
        for(int i=0;i<time.length;i++){
            time[i]=Integer.toString(i);
        }

        numberPicker.setMaxValue(90);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(time);
To 22 mjesto kaze na:  time[i]=Integer.toString(i);

Comment: Poozz iz Slovenije brate! :)

Comment: Back to english (msm da je kaznjivo na srpskom). You have to also map it in the activity #2, e.g. you get 9 , map it to 90 etc. About that error try the good old implicit conversion as in: `time[i]=""+i;` and revert the setMaxValue to 9, because you do have 9 values which you will map to numbers 10, 20, 30 etc

Comment: Brate kako to mislis You just need to map those positions back to the values?? Pa vidim,da mi vrati position a ne brojeve. Kako da to uradim u mom primeru kao u kodi gore(original kodi)???

Comment: You can just take the position and do `position*10` and it'll work in your case, right? If you need a more complicated mapping, you can always use key-value pairs, hashMap, etc. but for this simple example, multiplying by 10 will do the trick

Comment: Vucko,thanks for everything!!! You saved me :) At the end I used your advice and have put position*10 in my original code and it worked! (Imas neki mail?) Cheers

Comment: vucic94@yahoo.com
No problem, mate :D daj plus na odgovor uzivaj

Answer (score 0):

Try converting int to string like this

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(msg));
```

Do check your "x" variable before sending it across whether it contains the data you want to send or not

Comment: Hi Arshad,thank you for reply. I have tried your way and unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: remove this line from onClickListener "NumberPicker numberPicker= (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);" 
You are reinitializing the NumberPicker which will reset its value. Before adding "x" to intent check whether its sending the correct value to next activity. Use Log.e("TAG", x+"")

Comment: Thank you Arshad, I have used your advices and works